# Looking for words in a 2D array of chars in java. Why am I having search problems if certain parts are not commented out?

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array, traversal, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this method that searches for a word from an array of words in a grid of characters. It searches left to right, right to left, up to down, down to up, vertical up to the left, vertical up to the right, vertical down to the left, and vertical down to the right.

When I comment out all directions but one, for example I am trying to find a word that goes diagonally, it works, but when all directions are not commented out when I try to run it, only a few of the words come back that I am trying to search for.

The list of words I am looking for is:

```
SCALA
JAVA
ALGOS
ALGORITHM
SLUG
SLUR
GOES
TURTLE
```

When I ran my program, it found SCALA and JAVA, but then gave me an index out of bounds exception after when it tried looking for ALGOS. However, when I comment out all directions and search for the direction I know ALGOS is in, it gives me no problems.

What is wrong with my code that it does this and how can I fix it? Thank you.

```
public static String findWord(char[][]board, String word) {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {

                // search to the right
                    if (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row][col+letters]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    } // end search to the right

                    // search to the left
                    if (col - (word.length()-1) >= 0) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row][col-letters]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        } 
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    } // end search to the left

                    // search down
                    if (row + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row+letters][col]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        } 
                    } // end search down

                    // search up
                    if (row - (word.length()-1) >= 0) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row-letters][col]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    } // end search up 

                    // search diagonal up to right
                    if((row - (word.length()-1) <= 0) && (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length)) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row-letters][col+letters]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    }
                    // end search diagonal up to right

                    // search diagonal up to left
                    if((row - (word.length()-1) >= 0) && (col - (word.length()-1) >= 0)) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row-letters][col-letters]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    } // end search diagonal up to left

                    // search diagonal down to right
                    if((row + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) && (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length)) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row+letters][col+letters]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    } // end search diagonal down to right

                    // search diagonal down to left
                    if((row + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) && (col - (word.length()-1) >=0)) {
                        boolean foundWord = true;

                        for (int letters = 0; letters < word.length(); letters++) {
                            if (word.charAt(letters) != board[row+letters][col-letters]) {
                                foundWord = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(foundWord) {
                            return word + " Found at: " + Arrays.toString(new int[] {row,col});
                        }
                    }
                    // end search diagonal down to left 


            }
        }
        return word + " not found";
    } // end method findWord
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After just eyeballing it, try chaning this:

`// search right
if (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) {`

to this:

`// search right
if (col + (word.length()-1) < board[row].length) {`

EDIT:

Also, change this:

`//search down
if (row + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) {`

to this:

`//search down
if (row + (word.length()-1) < board.length) {`

This:

`// search diagonal up to right
if((row - (word.length()-1) <= 0) && (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length)) {`
To this:
`// search diagonal up to right
if((row - (word.length()-1) >= 0) && (col + (word.length()-1) < board[row].length)) {`

This:

`// search diagonal down to right
if((row + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) && (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length)`

To this:

`// search diagonal down to right
if((row + (word.length()-1) < board.length) && (col + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length)`

This:

`// search diagonal down to left
                    if((row + (word.length()-1) <= board[row].length) && (col - (word.length()-1) >=0)) {`

To This:

`// search diagonal down to left
if((row + (word.length()-1) < board.length) && (col - (word.length()-1) >=0)) {`

FINAL EDIT:
Just want to explain what's going on here.  There are just some simple oversights with the bounds of your checking.  I make these little errors all of the time, and they're the hardest to find.  But, just be aware of your bounds.  Checking if `index <= board[row].length` allows index to become the length of the array, which is fundamentally never an index in the array (excluding associative arrays!).  You also did `if (index <= 0 && ...)` at one point, which would eliminate an entire direction from the search at all points but the first row/column.

Comment: Sorry I had to edit so much.  After noticing the bug in some places, I noticed it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for changing it for me, and great explanation too. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would make the search wrap around the grid? I have been thinking that I would need to change the bounds but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sure, instead of checking if the cell is out of bounds, do `if (letter > board[row].length) templetter -= board[row].length` where templetter is `int templetter = letter;` at the beginning of the for loop.  Similarly do `if (letter < 0) templetter += board[row].length`

Comment: I'm confused as to what it would replace. Does the if (letter > board[row].length) templetter -= board[row].length go in place of one of these boundary checks if (col - (word.length()-1) >= 0) { ? Where would int templetter = letter; go?

Comment: 'templetter = letters + col' should go after each `for (int letter...)`.  Then, check if templetter is out of bounds, and wrap it if it is.  It's just so you can wrap the letter without affecting the flow of the for loop.  Then, wherever you check for if the letters match, use templetter as the index instead.  For example: `if (word.charAt(letter) != board[row][templetter]) {`.